# Vertical line between caption and the head of the table

Tags: longtabu

When I draw the following table, a vertical line appears between the head of the table and the bottom of the caption. (When I don't insert the caption the line disappears)

I use longtabu because this table spans multiple pages in my thesis

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{caption}                            
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                  
\usepackage{tabu}                           
\usepackage{lipsum}                         
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {X[2.0] | X[0.3]}
\caption{\textit{The caption of this table}}\\
\label{test-table}\\

\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} \textbf{Title 1} & \textbf{Title 2}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\hline
\endlastfoot

\multicolumn{2}{l} {{\cellcolor{lightgray!20}\textbf{Subtitle 1}}} \\
\hline 
test 1        & 1     \\
test 2        & 2     \\
test 3        & 3     \\
test 4        & 4     \\
test 5        & 5     \\
test 6        & 6     \\

\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

The result is as follows:

[image: vertical line caption]

Is there a way to remove this vertical line? Or is there another way to create these vertical lines in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the caption and the label inside the `longtabu` environnement and this create a newline. A hack may be to add a `cline` to avoid the vertical line:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{caption}                            
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                  
\usepackage{tabu}                           
\usepackage{lipsum}                         
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {X[2.0] | X[0.3]}
\caption{\textit{The caption of this table}}
\label{test-table}\\

\cline{1-2}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} \textbf{Title 1} & \textbf{Title 2}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\hline
\endlastfoot

\multicolumn{2}{l} {{\cellcolor{lightgray!20}\textbf{Subtitle 1}}} \\
\hline 
test 1        & 1     \\
test 2        & 2     \\
test 3        & 3     \\
test 4        & 4     \\
test 5        & 5     \\
test 6        & 6     \\

\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

If you do not need to span your document on several page you can also use a `table` environnement:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{caption}                            
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                  
\usepackage{tabu}                           
\usepackage{lipsum}                         
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]


\begin{table}
\caption{\textit{The caption of this table}}
\label{MET-classification}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {X[2.0] | X[0.3]}

\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} \textbf{Title 1} & \textbf{Title 2}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\hline
\endlastfoot

\multicolumn{2}{l} {{\cellcolor{lightgray!20}\textbf{Subtitle 1}}} \\
\hline 
test 1        & 1     \\
test 2        & 2     \\
test 3        & 3     \\
test 4        & 4     \\
test 5        & 5     \\
test 6        & 6     \\

\end{longtabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: In this way the table can't span across multiple pages because "the table environment cannot be split across pages"

Comment: @Hette see my edit